# Can we use some kind of array to control the fields on the form?

Tags: textbox

I have a asp.net form with 20 textbox controls(VB2012 and 2008R2). Is there an array function for me to change the property of all the fields or do I have to spell it out separately. Example changing the back color and making the control editable when the edit button is clicked.

Thanks
~ Nita

Comment: In ASP.NET there is the Repeater control. With it you can put just one TextBox and repeat it 20 times, for example. You can start looking http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Comment: Tony, mine is not a table. It is the form to collect patron data like name, address...... I want all the fields to be disabled on load and enable for editing(onclick of a button).

Comment: I  just used the templates for editing and inserting the data items instead of writing the custom code.

Answer (score 0):

I did this sometime ago:

```
void SetEnabled(bool enable)
{
    textBox1.enabled = enable;
    textBox1.enabled = enable;
    textBox2.enabled = enable;
    textBox3.enabled = enable;
    textBox4.enabled = enable;
    textBox5.enabled = enable;
    ... repeat until textBox20
    textBox20.enabled = enable;
}
```

to call it, for example:

```
SetEnabled(true);
```

or

```
SetEnabled(false);
```

Comment: So how do you call it?